# Python function - Check for a string which appears multiple time in a text file

Tags: python, function

For the input i have two files (`first.arxml`, `second.arxml`) and after running the source code, i obtain a .log file in which appears on multiple and separate lines my initial two files names (`first.arxml`, `second.arxml`):

```html
bla bla: other lines
2018-04-23 16:18:13,733 INFO The file: C:\Users\...\rte_config\first.arxml is well-formed
2018-04-23 16:18:13,733 INFO The file: C:\Users\...\rte_config\second.arxml is well-formed
bla bla: other lines
2018-04-23 16:18:13,733 INFO The file: C:\Users\...\rte_config\first.arxml is well-formed
2018-04-23 16:18:13,733 INFO The file: C:\Users\...\rte_config\second.arxml is well-formed
bla bla: other lines
```

Well, my code until now is:

```html
 def checkParsing(path1, path2, extension, message):
        """
        path1 = used for taking the .arxml files name
        path2 = used for defining the file to be checked
        message = string to be matched
        extension = file extension
        """
        all_files = []
        found_files = []
        #for file in os.listdir(path1):
        #     if file.endswith(extension):
        #          all_files.append(file)
        for path, dirs, file in os.walk(path1):
            for f in file:
                if f.endswith(extension):
                    all_files.append(f)
        for file in all_files:
            found_files.append(False)
        datafile = open(path2)
        line_file = datafile.readline()
        i = 0
        while line_file != "":
            for files in all_files:
                if files + " " + message in line_file:
                    found_files[i] = True
                    i =i + 1
            line_file = datafile.readline()
        for item in found_files:
            if item == False:
                return False
        return True
```

Having initially two files(`first.arxml`and `second.arxml`), so there are two boolean values in `found_files`, when i run unittest it does not pass due to the second appearance of each name in .log file. How can i solve this issue? Where m'i wrong?

Comment: So what is your problem?  As far as I can see, your function appears to do that.  (It can probably be faster: Make `all_files` a set and remove elements as soon as you find them.  Return `True` from the function as soon as `all_files` is empty.)

Comment: @MartinBonner - that's it! Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify that the code works, but you want to make it faster.  Also, don't edit answers into your question - if you have an answer, create an answer.  That way I can comment about the problem you (may) have introduced.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MartinBonner:

```html
    def checkParsing(path1, path2, extension, message):
        """
        path1 = used for taking the .arxml files name
        path2 = used for defining the file to be checked
        message = string to be matched
        extension = file extension
        """
        all_files = []
        for path, dirs, file in os.walk(path1):
            for f in file:
                if f.endswith(extension):
                    all_files.append(f)
        datafile = open(path2)
        line_file = datafile.readline()
        i = 0
        while line_file != "" and all_files:
            for files in all_files:
                if files + " " + message in line_file:
                    all_files.remove(files)
                    i = i + 1
            line_file = datafile.readline()
        if not all_files:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```